# infinite scroll with content loop inside a fixed div

Tags: jquery, html, css, loops, scroll

does anybody know a solution for the following problem?

i tried to make a infinite scroll with content loop inside a fixed div,
i´ve modified this code... but when i try to make the ".content" div fixed and give him a defined hight it kills always the whole code.

thanks

```js
$(function() {
    // every 1 seconds, check + update
    setInterval(appendContent, 400);
    setInterval(continueScrolling, 100);
});

var b = $('.content');

// if almost at bottom, append more content
function appendContent() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() * 2 > $(".content").height()) {
        b.html(b.html() + b.html()); // double content
    }    
}

// continue scrolling linearly
function continueScrolling() {
    y = $(window).scrollTop();
    $("html, body").stop().animate({
        scrollTop: y+1000
    }, {
        duration: 10000,
        easing: 'linear',
        queue: false
    });
}


var page = $("html, body");

$(function() {

   page.on("scroll mousedown wheel DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup touchmove", function(){
       page.stop();
   });

   page.animate({ scrollTop: $(this).position().top }, 'slow', function(){
       page.off("scroll mousedown wheel DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup touchmove");
   });

   return false; 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">
============================<br>
test1<br>
test2<br>
test3<br>
test4<br>
test5<br>
============================<br>
test1<br>
test2<br>
test3<br>
test4<br>
test5<br>
============================<br>
test1<br>
test2<br>
test3<br>
test4<br>
test5<br>
============================<br>
test1<br>
test2<br>
test3<br>
test4<br>
test5<br>
============================<br>
test1<br>
test2<br>
test3<br>
test4<br>
test5<br>
============================<br>
test1<br>
test2<br>
test3<br>
test4<br>
test5<br>
============================<br>
test1<br>
test2<br>
test3<br>
test4<br>
test5<br>
============================<br>
test1<br>
test2<br>
test3<br>
test4<br>
test5<br>
============================<br>
test1<br>
test2<br>
test3<br>
test4<br>
test5<br>
============================<br>
test1<br>
test2<br>
test3<br>
test4<br>
test5<br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What height are you trying to define? If the number is too small you'll be creating a lot of DOM elements with each iteration of the loop, that can potentially kill the browser rendering the code. Try increasing the interval between each refresh and lower the content added each time.

About the position fixed, well, you are telling the element to freeze in place so it can stay there wherever you go. This function is normally used in sticky headers or nav bars, I don't get why would you want to use it here.